# "within" or "during" which is appropriate for a comparative sentence?

Tags: prepositions, comparative-constructions

Consider: The revolving door rotates 360 degrees. When the revolving door is in rotational position A corresponding to a rotation angle of 30 degrees, the force required to start turning it is five newton.  When the revolving door is in the other rotational positions, the force is one newton.  I created the sentence below to describe this:

> When the revolving door is in rotational position A, the force
>   required to start turning it has a maximum value **within/during** its one rotation/revolution.

I would like to know which of "within" and "during" is appropriate for the sentence above.

Comment: **becomes maximum** is not really idiomatic.  reaches its maximum?

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to say here. Is it that "When the revolving door is in that position, the force required to turn it a single revolution is maximal." Do I infer correctly that the force required to turn the door on its axis varies according to its rotational position?

Comment: Your assumption "varies according to its rotational position" is correct.

Comment: So you're speaking about the force required to turn the door a single revolution starting at various rotational positions . One of those positions requires the greatest force. *When the door is in that rotational position, the force required to turn it a single revolution is at its maximum*.  But that strikes me as an odd reification of the force.  *When the door starts in that rotational position, it takes the greatest amount of force to turn it a single revolution.*   I really don't see what "during" or "within" adds to your meaning.

Comment: I edited my question to make clear what I questioned.

Comment: You would not use **within** or **during** with that scenario: you're speaking about the amount of force required to **start the door turning**. That value of 5 newtons corresponds to the amount of inertia that must be overcome when the door is at 30 degrees, correct?

Comment: You would use **during** if you were speaking about the amount of force required to **keep the door turning**.

Comment: Thank you for you comments, but I cannot explain well. I wait for answers from others.